# add more than one property in a form symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form type where I will add an entity and add more than one attribute

```
$builder ->add('number', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Numberrange',
              'property' => 'De'
              'multiple' => false,));
```

In the property I want to add another field ie

```
$builder ->add('number', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Numberrange',
              'property' => 'De','A'
              'multiple' => false,));
```

How could I do it?

```
->add('subnumbers', 'collection', array('type'         => new SubnumberType(),
                                              'allow_add'    => true,
                                              'allow_delete' => true))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, property only allows a `string` as a parameter: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property

The solution in your case would be to leave the `property` blank and then implement the `__toString()` method in your Entity.

First change the way you define your form type (pass a blank value to property):

```
$builder ->add('number', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Numberrange',
              'multiple' => false,));
```

Second, define the `__toString()` function in your `TelnOperatorBundle:Numberrange` entity:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->De . ' : ' . $this->A;
}
```

Comment: but how to call __toString then? I mean where in the Type?@cheesemacfly

Comment: You don't need to call it: `[property] If left blank, the entity object will be cast into a string and so must have a __toString() method.`

Comment: the _toString() must be in the entity or in the entity Type? @cheesemacfly

Comment: In `TelnOperatorBundle:Numberrange` definition.

Comment: It may be a related question, but If I want to do the same thing with a collection. I will join the code. Could u plz have a look ? @cheesemacfly